# jQuery - Add class to last 2 elements only if length is more than 5

Tags: jquery

How can I add CSS class to **last 2 `<li>`** elements only the parent `<ul>` has more than **5 `<li>`** elements.

> **HTML**

```
<div id="mymenu">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
        <li>Item 6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

> **jQuery**

```
$('#mymenu ul li:last-child').prev('li').andSelf().addClass("red");
```

---

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ReddyPrasad/pkkb7f3b/)

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional approach

```
//cache the lis since we need to use it again
var $lis = $('#mymenu ul li');
//check if there are more than 5 elements
if ($lis.length > 5) {
    //if so get the last 2 elements and add the class
    $lis.slice(-2).addClass("red");
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rLu3jweh/)

- [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

Comment: sorry not sure what you mean... what is the expected output

Comment: I think all the solutions provided here does that... then what is the problem

Comment: Excellent.. this is what exactly I want... Kudos to your help and I am voting up your Answer... Thanks mate...

Answer (score 2):

You can count the children using:

`$('#mymenu ul').children().length`,

basically:

```
if($('#mymenu ul').children().length > 5)
    $('#mymenu ul li:last-child').prev('li').andSelf().addClass("red");
```

Comment: Cool... Working Great... Thanks for the Answer

Comment: Great!! Glad to be of help! :)

Comment: Can you please check my latest **FIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/ReddyPrasad/pkkb7f3b/ where is it correct way of doing it or not? Actually what I want is, I want to add one more class to before elements as well for the same scenario...

Answer (score 1):

just add if statement to check the length/total of the `li` before you add the class

```
if($('#mymenu ul li').length > 5)
    $('#mymenu ul li:last-child').prev('li').andSelf().addClass("red");
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pkkb7f3b/1/)

Comment: Hi @Kyojimaru,  Thanks for the reply...

Can you please check my latest [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ReddyPrasad/pkkb7f3b/) where is it correct way of doing it or not? Actually what I want is, I want to add one more class to before elements as well for the same scenario...